# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCF05E675B (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, native

I've developed an **UWP app**, for which I have already managed to build and publish package on the Store, without any problem.
As some users encounter performances problems, I would like to test my last changes by compiling the code with "**.Net Native tool chain**".

But I get an exception before the end of the build:
[image]
If I uncheck the case "**Compile with .NET Native tool chain**", there is no longer problem.

The other builds parameters are "**Release**" and "**x64**".

Would you have any idea? Why didn't I encounter this exception when I've created my packages?

**[Edit] 2017-02-13 : what's new**

I have some news about this problem.

Firstly, the Store version has new "bug" that seems to raise when leaving a page through OnNavigatedFrom():

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel = this.DataContext as DetailsViewModel;
    if (!ViewModel.ToChildNavigate)
    {
        // Dispose resources
        this.Resources.Clear();
        this.Loaded -= DetailsPage_Loaded;
        ViewModel = null;
    }
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);            
}
```

In Debug mode, this code works very well...

I have also remarked that I can actually compile in "**Release**" mode with "**.Net Native tool chain**". But it only works until a usser logged in.

At the launch of the app, there are 2 possibilities:

- at the first launch, or if no user is logged, the app goes on a "**Login**" page
- when a user has successfully logged in, the user account is saved in a Storage file, and the app goes on the "**Home**" page

The error message ("Unhandled exception...") only appears after the user sucessfully logged in, so the use of the file could be an explanation. But as I can't use breakpoints in "Release" mode, I'm not sure at all...

Here are the last lines of the "Output" window:

> 'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msv1_0.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\NtlmShared.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptdll.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Dyna6164b5c9#\2e1e02d5c22607472a9047fbf3c27616\System.Dynamic.Runtime.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runtcf595564#\31f53d6bf5e2b71b24f4ce2030dd28e9\System.Runtime.Numerics.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Numerics\5237480aedaa4904c6fd85dae99af471\System.Numerics.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runteb92aa12#\213003369298faf75651a6b8981dce12\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml.XDocument\fa16b0c36bab379f0bf98c050f57b3f6\System.Xml.XDocument.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml.Linq\6e975e2acfc33e1c706f00bf2942e187\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Text2f5a8366#\25f6a0dc41a72364fd9b2a2ea662ec8e\System.Text.RegularExpressions.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Colldfb0b5ae#\0b99eb4fa4efaf834ac44e036afc8530\System.Collections.Concurrent.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Linqa402077a#\203c9b8ac6a2ed5bc6fd77011eada55c\System.Linq.Queryable.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.14393.447_none_5507ded2cb4f7f4c\comctl32.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Refl588a0515#\1e199ee46bc1cbfe8da8b25cf617bb6e\System.Reflection.Primitives.ni.dll'. 
>   'ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is native, and native debugging is currently disabled.
>   Unhandled exception at 0x068F73C8 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in ComponentAnalysisReport.UWP.exe: 0xC000027B: Une exception interne de l’application s’est produite (parameters: 0x15732DD0, 0x00000002).

***How could I debug my app in "Release" mode under Visual Studio? Why are there always differences between the Store version and "Release" version?***

Regards...

Comment: Native would be x86 mode, not x64.  To get native to work you probably would have to rebuild entire project using x86.  Normally I would do this by deleting the bin folder in project which forces everything to get rebuilt.

Comment: Hi jdweng, I encounter exactly the same error if I debug in x86 mode.

Comment: Did you press continue?

Comment: Yes of course: if I press continue the same message appars again and again.

Comment: See following : https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28714425/Application-Error-in-Windows-10.html

Comment: Hi jdweng, I have tested the 2 solutions (SFC /SCANNOW and DISM.exe) but it didn't change anything...

Comment: Do you get this when compiling a brand new (blank) project? If you do it would indicate a problem with your installation. If not then it's something in your code. Without a repro ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) for the problem it's going to be a struggle to help further.

Comment: @MattLacey If I compile a new blank project, there isn't any problem.
So the problem probably comes from my project (code, NuGet package, ...).
What is really strange is that I can create a package for the Store without any problem, whereas it is a native compilation too...

Comment: I was facing the same error at runtime (Release/Debug Mode). This started when I added a `Border` around an `Image` in a `ListView ItemTemplate`. When I removed it the error was gone. Now, go figure :)

Comment: Hi @Gold.strike, did you find any solution for the problem, because i am also facing the same kind of issue. My UWP app is working fine in debug mode whereas it is failing in the certification test in Crashes and Hangs and creating a dump file. How to resolve?

Comment: Hi @BhanuprakashMankala, I apologize but as I've explained, I was finally able to build the app in Release mode in some conditions. My problem actually comes from a Syncfusion control, and I found another way to fix it.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi @Gold.strike, my app was finally passes certification. My problem comes from Reflection which i was used in my code. So because of reflection it fails in the certification process. And thank you for reply.