# Difference between debug mode and the Store App

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, binding, uwp, store

I have developed an **UWP app** that is currently in test through the **Store**.
I encounter **a strange problem** with the **Store** version, that doesn't occur when I build the app from **Visual Studio**: this is really hard for me to understand it or debug it...

It is about a **basic Binding** in a **ComboBox**:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CoreOrderType}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding CarForm.core_order_type, Mode=TwoWay}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      />
```

- At the opening of the page, this ComboBox "**Order Type**" **is well filled** if the app is launched from **Visual Studio**:

[image: Visual Studio - ComboBox is filled]

- But it's not the case from the **Store** version:

This ComboBox "**Order Type**" **is empty**:
[image: Store - ComboBox is empty]

But it **contains the expected value** if the list is opened:
[image: Store - But value is present]

***=> Would you have any explanation? How could I debug this?***

**Edit1: add of the relevant code from the ViewModel and the Model**

**Properties**:

```
private Car_Forms _carForm;
public Car_Forms CarForm
{
    get { return _carForm; }
    set
    {
        this._carForm = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CarForm);
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<V_Core_Order> _vCoreOrders;
public ObservableCollection<V_Core_Order> VCoreOrders
{
    get { return _vCoreOrders; }
    set { Set(ref _vCoreOrders, value); }
}
```

=> **CarForm** is the "root" object of my page, and **VCoreOrders** is the list attached to the ComboBox

**Constructor:**

```
public DetailsViewModel(Guid? id)
{
    ...
    // Load Car_Forms
    LoadDatas(id);
}
```

=> in the constructor I call the **LoadDatas()** method, which load the details of the form and the lists

**Model**:

```
private string _core_order_type;
[MaxLength(200), NotNull]
public string core_order_type
{
    get
    {   return _core_order_type; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _core_order_type)
        {
            _core_order_type = value;
            if (value != null || value != string.Empty)
                core_order_type_error = false;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => core_order_type);
        }
    }
}
```

=> when I place breakpoint in the Setter, I can see that **value** is never null

**Edit2: add of new details and video link**

Finally the problem doesn't only occurs on the Store version, so this is not a problem of "Native code":

- if I launch the app **from Visual Studio**: this problem **never** occurs
- if I relaunch the app **outside of Visual Studio**: this problem occurs **randomly**

I've also added a **TextBlock** that is binded to the same item: **CarForm.core_order_type**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CarForm.core_order_type, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I've uploaded a short video that shows the opening of the same form: we can see that the problem occurs the first time, but not the following times:
[bug in video](https://youtu.be/86MXgdVEYas)

In practice, the error can occur several times: it's really randomally.

Comment: Can you reproduce this when you run from Visual Studio in Release mode?

Comment: Yes it's the same thing in "Release" mode. But in "Release" mode, I have unchecked the option "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" cause this reaises exceptions for me. I have opened another topic about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576122/unhandled-exception-at-0x00007ffcf05e675b-windows-ui-xaml-dll

Comment: A side question - have you tried to use `x:Bind` instead of runtime `Binding`?

Comment: But if I use "x:Bind", the Binding couldn't be in mode TwoWay, isn't it?

Comment: x:Bind you can set the mode also to two way; same as doing with binding.

Comment: @Gold.strike [It can be defined with *TwoWay* mode.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) No problem with that.

Comment: can you show the relevant code from your viewmodel?

Comment: Please share the code for the viewModel or the relevant code from your BaseViewModel(s) if any

Comment: Race condition - means your order type could be populated _before_ the type list gets populated.

Comment: I have add some details of my ViewModel: please let me know if I must complete it...

Comment: You don't raise PropertyChanged in your second ObservableCollection. Maybe this?

Comment: Please check the .Net native option, and  test under release mode firstly to tell the result.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Sorry, I can't check this option, as I have explained in a previous post. This occurs me an error that I can't solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576122/unhandled-exception-at-0x00007ffcf05e675b-windows-ui-xaml-dll

Comment: @Gold.strike the difference between what you build and what goes in the store is that the store compiles your app using the .Net Native toolchain. From the above it seems that the issue is due to something behaving differently when compiled this way. It's very unlikely that the issue can be debugged without being able to compile in this mode and so you need to address that problem before you can solve this. A repro (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also likely be helpful

Comment: In fact, the problem is not related to the "Native tool chain": I've finally managed to reproduce it when I build the app in "Debug" mode.
But the error never occurs when I debug through Visual Studio, but only when I relaunch the app after...